Ruby - new error - "object allocation during garbage collection phase"
I upgrade an already running ruby application to 3.3.5 and it seems a new bug has arrived.
It is a "C" extension and I'm now confused about the GC in ruby. Let's start…

I using a rb_protect in C to protect a call to a ruby callback from my library

mk_inline VALUE NS(sRescue) (
  MK_RT_ARGS
  MK_MNG const mng,
  VALUE(*proc)(ANYARGS),
  VALUE data
) {
  int state;
  VALUE ret = rb_protect(proc, data, &state);
  if (state) {
    OT_ERROR_LNG_2_MQ(mng);
  }
  return ret;
}

The ruby-code called has a BUG and the OT_ERROR_LNG_2_MQ is called to work on the error-message.
...
  } else if (rb_obj_is_kind_of(ex, rb_eStandardError) == Qtrue) {
    static VALUE sym_highlight = 0;
    if (!sym_highlight) sym_highlight = ID2SYM(rb_intern_const("highlight"));
    VALUE opt = rb_hash_new();
    rb_hash_aset(opt, sym_highlight, Qfalse);
    VALUE msg = rb_funcallv_kw(ex,MK(id_full_message),1,&opt,RB_PASS_KEYWORDS);
    MkErrorSetC (err, VAL2STRN(msg), MK(Get_Call_Proc)(0,NULL), -1);    
    rb_set_errinfo(Qnil);
  } ...

now the MK(id_full_message) = rb_intern("full_message"); create the object allocation during garbage collection phase error.
My problem is NOT the error message, my problem is that I have NO clue how to avoid this error.

the GC is called from RUBY in a "random" manner
my "code" does NOT interact with the GC
from my point of view this GC message is a "BUG" generator out of control of the target programmer.

My question is now → How can I avoid this kind of error because I'm not able to avoid a "object-creation" in the RUBY standard function full_message ?
UPDATE
After some research and switching from ruby-3.3.5 to ruby-3.2.5 the error disappeared.
The core problem is probably described in ruby-3.3.5/NEWS.md :
### GC / Memory management

* Major performance improvements over Ruby 3.2
    * Young objects referenced by old objects are no longer immediately
      promoted to the old generation. This significantly reduces the frequency of
      major GC collections. [[Feature #19678]]
    * A new `REMEMBERED_WB_UNPROTECTED_OBJECTS_LIMIT_RATIO` tuning variable was
      introduced to control the number of unprotected objects cause a major GC
      collection to trigger. The default is set to `0.01` (1%). This significantly
      reduces the frequency of major GC collection. [[Feature #19571]]
    * Write Barriers were implemented for many core types that were missing them,
      notably `Time`, `Enumerator`, `MatchData`, `Method`, `File::Stat`, `BigDecimal`
      and several others. This significantly reduces minor GC collection time and major
      GC collection frequency.
    * Most core classes are now using Variable Width Allocation, notably `Hash`, `Time`,
      `Thread::Backtrace`, `Thread::Backtrace::Location`, `File::Stat`, `Method`.
      This makes these classes faster to allocate and free, use less memory and reduce
      heap fragmentation.
* `defined?(@ivar)` is optimized with Object Shapes.

An Change to the GC in ruby (performance improvement ;-) this seems to be more an "out-of-business-improvement"
UPDATE
add some infos about this problem at: http://thedev.nhi1.de/NHI1/main/RUBY.htm

I think in order to provide a reasonable answer we'd need to see how this code is used in practice. Try to set up a minimal reproducible example which demonstrates the issue
